# How can I test an infinite loop bug in R

Tags: r, testing, infinite-loop

I have a bug in my R code that causes an infinite loop. I'd like to write a test that checks I have fixed this bug.

```r
foo <- function () {
  while (TRUE) sleep(1) # oops!
}

# I want something like:
expect_completes_within(foo(), seconds = 10)
```

Is there any existing solution? Is there a way to interrupt execution and throw an error after a given time?

Comment: Something like this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460702/get-out-of-infinite-while-loop

Comment: The problem is that the real loop is part of the code to be tested, so I can't reach into it to add e.g. a timer. (Obviously, in fact I will change the code and hopefully fix the bug, but the testing code shouldn't do that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R.utils::withTimeout(foo(), timeout = 10) # Stop foo() after 10 seconds.
```

Solution has already been found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462416/r-set-execution-time-limit-in-loop), where also code in base R has been provided.

Comment: `base::setTimeLimit()` is perfect.